# Coalesce function for PHP?

Tags: php, optimization, null-coalescing-operator

Many programming languages have a coalesce function (returns the first non-NULL value, [example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)). PHP, sadly in 2009, does not.

What would be a good way to implement one in PHP until PHP itself gets a coalesce function?

Comment: Related: the new [null coalescing operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26142784/418413) `??` for PHP 7.

Comment: More information about the null coalesce operator can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666256/null-coalesce-operator-in-php

Comment: Just to Note, PHP7 Implemented this fucntion

Comment: @Grzegorz: An operator is not a function, or where did you find that function new in PHP 7 ;)

Comment: By function i did not mean function ;) Feature. I wasn't precise. Thank you :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

PHP 7 introduced a real [coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
echo $_GET['doesNotExist'] ?? 'fallback'; // prints 'fallback'
```

If the value before the `??` does not exists or is `null` the value after the `??` is taken.

The improvement over the mentioned `?:` operator is, that the `??` also handles undefined variables without throwing an `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: Finally no more isset() and empty() all over the place!

Comment: @timeNomad you will still need is empty, it checks for null only

Comment: The only way to get safe "falsy-coalesce" is to use a bit of both: `($_GET['doesNotExist'] ?? null) ?: 'fallback'`

Comment: The advantage of `?:` over `??`, however, is that it coalesces empty values as well which `??` does not do. Similar to the behavior of the logical OR operator in JavaScript (i.e. `$val || 'default'`), I would find `?:` to be a more practical form of *coalescing* if in our practice we ultimately find ourselves handling both *empty* and *null* in the same way (i.e. `$val ?: 'default'`). And if you want to force the issue further and swallow `E_NOTICE`, you could argue this even: `echo @$val ?: 'default';`

Comment: Will it give fatal error if used in libraries that sill support php older versions like 5.5?

Answer (score 203):

There is a new operator in php 5.3 which does this: `?:`

```
// A
echo 'A' ?: 'B';

// B
echo '' ?: 'B';

// B
echo false ?: 'B';

// B
echo null ?: 'B';
```

Source: http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0

Comment: What about multiple ternary shortcuts, would something like "echo $a ?: $b ?: $c ?: $d;" work?

Comment: Does not work as expected for arrays. For example when trying to check if an undefined array element is falsey will result in an error.   `$input['properties']['range_low'] ?: '?'`

Comment: You should get an Undefined Index notice irrespective of using the coalesce operator.

Comment: [from the manual for the Ternary Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary): Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise

Comment: Too bad that `or` doesn't work like this in PHP. (It does the job in Python, for instance)

Comment: Multiple falsey arguments return the last argument, `array() ?: null ?: false` returns `false`.  The operator is indeed sane.

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't just accept non-null like coalesce in other languages, but any value, which will be implicitly converted to a boolean. So make sure you brush up on your [type casting rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: I just spent the last hour scratching my head with my code and finally realized it was my use of this coalescing operator, which as shown in this answer, takes the first NON-FALSY (!!!) value. This is different than the null coalescing operator I want. :-(

Comment: As DanMan said, this is not a "coalesce" as the title suggests. The answer from Will Shaver is actually coalesce. Coalesce returns the first non-null value. ($value ?: $other) is the same as ($value ? $value : $other). So, if $value === false then $other is returned. A true coalesce would return false because $value is non-null.

Answer (score 30):

First hit for "php coalesce" on google.

```
function coalesce() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  foreach ($args as $arg) {
    if (!empty($arg)) {
      return $arg;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

http://drupial.com/content/php-coalesce

Comment: Save a tiny bit of ram and don't duplicate the args into an array, just do    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {}

Comment: @TravisO I believe that caching func_get_args() is faster because it will save data in variable instead of calculating for every loop

Comment: @TravisO yeah like Alfred said, if you bring the call to func_get_args() into the loop condition it'll get called each time - PHP can't tell that the function result won't change each time.

Comment: @[Alfred,Ciaran] - you are incorrect.  foreach() evaluates the first argument only once, to get an array, and then iterates over it.

Comment: Putting func_get_args() inside the foreach (here as $arg) won't change anything from a performance point of view.

Comment: @Savageman ... exactly ... if you are thinking of squeezing this millisecond of performance or few bytes of memory out of your application you're probably looking at the wrong performance/memory bottleneck

Comment: Ironically, this is now the first hit for "php coalesce" on Google.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (!is_null($arg)) {`, since coalesce should return the first non-null value (even if it's 0, `false` or something else falsey).

Comment: This is not "real" coalesce function

Answer (score 18):

I really like the ?: operator. Unfortunately, it is not yet implemented on my production environment. So I use the equivalent of this:

```
function coalesce() {
  return array_shift(array_filter(func_get_args()));
}
```

Comment: this is a 'truthy' coalesce, using array_filter to get rid of anything that evaluates to false (including null) in the n arguments passed in.  My guess is using shift instead of the first element in the array is somehow more robust, but that part I don't know. 

see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: I like it but have to agree with @hakre - `coalesce` is supposed to return the first *non-null* argument it encounters, which would include `FALSE`.  This function will discard `FALSE` though, probably not what op has in mind (at least not what I'd want out of a `coalesce` function).

Comment: Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 10):

It is worth noting that due to PHP's treatment of uninitalised variables and array indices, any kind of coalesce function is of limited use.  I would love to be able to do this:

```
$id = coalesce($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['id'], null);
```

But this will, in most cases, cause PHP to error with an E_NOTICE.  The only safe way to test the existence of a variable before using it is to use it directly in empty() or isset().  The ternary operator suggested by Kevin is the best option if you know that all the options in your coalesce are known to be initialised.

Comment: In this case, array unions work pretty nicely (`$getstuff = $_GET+$_SESSION+array('id'=>null);$id=$getstuff['id'];`).

Comment: @Quill what's that supposed to mean? Did you the suggested solution with reference?

Comment: PHP 7 introduces the lovely new [isset ternary](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) operator `??` to make this very common operation more concise.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you identify exactly how you want this function to work with certain types. PHP has a wide variety of type-checking or similar functions, so make sure you know how they work.  This is an example comparison of is_null() and empty()

```
$testData = array(
  'FALSE'   => FALSE
  ,'0'      => 0
  ,'"0"'    => "0"  
  ,'NULL'   => NULL
  ,'array()'=> array()
  ,'new stdClass()' => new stdClass()
  ,'$undef' => $undef
);

foreach ( $testData as $key => $var )
{
  echo "$key " . (( empty( $var ) ) ? 'is' : 'is not') . " empty<br>";
  echo "$key " . (( is_null( $var ) ) ? 'is' : 'is not')  . " null<br>";
  echo '<hr>';
}
```

As you can see, empty() returns true for all of these, but is_null() only does so for 2 of them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm expanding on the answer posted by [Ethan Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4688108/177920).  That answer will discard non-null arguments that evaluate to false due to the inner workings of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), which isn't what a `coalesce` function typically does.  For example:

```
echo 42 === coalesce(null, 0, 42) ? 'Oops' : 'Hooray';
```

> Oops

To overcome this, a second argument and function definition are required.  The *callable* function is responsible for telling `array_filter` whether or not to add the current array value to the result array:

```
// "callable"
function not_null($i){
    return !is_null($i);  // strictly non-null, 'isset' possibly not as much
}

function coalesce(){
    // pass callable to array_filter
    return array_shift(array_filter(func_get_args(), 'not_null'));
}
```

It would be nice if you could simply pass `isset` or `'isset'` as the 2nd argument to `array_filter`, but no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this, but I wonder if it couldn't be improved with some of the new features in PHP 5.

```
function coalesce() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  foreach ($args as $arg) {
    if (!empty($arg)) {
    return $arg;
    }
  }
  return $args[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3+, with closures:

```
function coalesce()
{
    return array_shift(array_filter(func_get_args(), function ($value) {
        return !is_null($value);
    }));
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/187365

Comment: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: Yup, I broke the strict rules for the demo, just to make it simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

A function to return the first non-NULL value:

```
  function coalesce(&...$args) { // ... as of PHP 5.6
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
      if (isset($arg)) return $arg;
    }
  }
```

Equivalent to `$var1 ?? $var2 ?? null` in PHP 7+.

A function to return the first non-empty value:

```
  function coalesce(&...$args) {
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
      if (!empty($arg)) return $arg;
    }
  }
```

Equivalent to `(isset($var1) ? $var1 : null) ?: (isset($var2) ? $var2 : null) ?: null` in PHP 5.3+.

The above will consider a numerical string of "0.00" as non-empty. Typically coming from a HTTP GET, HTTP POST, browser cookie or the MySQL driver passing a float or decimal as numerical string.

A function to return the first variable that is not undefined, null, (bool)false, (int)0, (float)0.00, (string)"", (string)"0", (string)"0.00", (array)[]:

```
  function coalesce(&...$args) {
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
      if (!empty($arg) && (!is_numeric($arg) || (float)$arg!= 0)) return $arg;
    }
  }
```

To be used like:

```
$myvar = coalesce($var1, $var2, $var3, ...);
```