# Does using a function in foreach loop caches the result, or calls the function each time?

Tags: php

In the following code:

```
function a(){
    echo 'a';
    return array(1,2,3,4);
}

foreach(a() as $t){
    echo $t;    
}
```

We can see a() is called only once, and it seems the returned value is cached...
But then I got to see [this debate (see comments on the question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013493/coalesce-function-for-php) am I missing something?

Comment: Try changing that to `for($a = 0; $a <= count(a()); $a++)` and see what you get :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, your test is conclusive.

It makes no sense for it to evaluate the first expression any more than once.  It's the basic premise of a foreach loop.

A `for` loop has three arguments, and it does evaluate the second and third each iteration.