# PHP loop X amount of times

Tags: php, loops

I have a string called `$columns` which dynamically gets a value from 1 to 7. I want to create a loop of `<td></td>` for however many times the value of `$columns` is. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
for ($k = 0 ; $k < $columns; $k++){ echo '<td></td>'; }
```

Comment: I use this with the loop amount set to 2, but it occasionally returns 1 instead of 2. Is there a better way to limit the loop? I don't want it to occasionally loop once. It must loop twice at all times. (FYI, I've tried it with a difference amount of loops, and it still occasionally loops -1 of the intended loop amount).

Answer (score 50):

Here's a more readable way to achieve this:

```
foreach(range(1,$columns) as $index) {
   //do your magic here
}
```

Comment: @tom - wouldn't `range()` be called first and the result of that is used in each iteration?

Comment: You are right @alexkb, range() will be evaluated only once. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891917/does-using-a-function-in-foreach-loop-caches-the-result-or-calls-the-function-e

Comment: Be very careful here. `range(1, 0)` gets executed two times, which may not be what you're expecting. A normal for loop doesn't have that issue.

Answer (score 13):

If you just need to use number of repeat count:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    // code to repeat here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I like this way:

```
while( $i++ < $columns ) echo $i;
```

Just bear in mind if `$columns` is 5, this will run 5 times (not 4).

*Edit: There seems to be some confusion around the initial state of `$i` here. You are welcome to initialise `$i=0` beforehand if you wish. This is not required however as PHP is a very helpful engine and will do it for you automatically (tho, it will throw a notice if you happen to have those enabled).*

Comment: You need to initialize $i with zero e.g. `$i = 0;`, so there will be one more line above it

Comment: I admit that comment was posted before trying exact code you posted. Anyway, I just tried it, and got the error

Comment: A notice you mean?

Comment: Yep notice, sorry not being precise enough :D

Answer (score 3):

just repeat $n times? ... if dont mind that $n goes backwards...
the advantage is that you can see/config "times" at the beginning

```
$n = 5;
while (--$n >= 0)
{
  // do something, remember that $n goes backwards;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `str_repeat()` function in PHP, which repeats a string a number of times. The solution for your problem would be:
`str_repeat( '<td></td>', $columns );`

Answer (score 2):

If `$columns` is a `string` you can cast to `int` and use a simple for loop

```
for ($i=1; $i<(int)$columns; $i++) {
   echo '<td></td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) will work:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run it through a for loop easily to achieve this

```
$myData = array('val1', 'val2', ...);

for( $i = 0; $i < intval($columns); $i++)
{
    echo "<td>" . $myData[$i] . "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why use logic at all, don't waste those CPU cycles!

```
<td colspan="<?php echo $columns; ?>"></td>
```