# Quicker $foo ? $foo : 'bar'

Tags: php, ternary-operator

A line of code speaks a gazillion words so:

```
$foo = false;
$bar = $foo ? $foo : 'bar';
/* $bar == 'bar' */

$foo = 'foo';
$bar = $foo ? $foo : 'bar';
/* $bar == 'foo' */
```

Is there a quicker way of saying "if something isn't false, then don't change it (if `$foo` isn't `false` then it stays as whatever it was, else, we'll change it)"?

Comment: As opposed to... an `if` statement?

Comment: "Quicker" not in terms of execution speed but in terms of coding I suppose?

Comment: "if something isn't false, then don't change it" Wait, that's not what your code is doing. Your code is always changing something.

Comment: I think he means as opposed to something like a `coalesce` statement, where as long as the value is set/non-false/non-null, you keep it, otherwise revert to a default value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013493/coalesce-function-for-php/1891899#1891899

Comment: Sorry, to specify: coding speed, not execution speed.

Thanks for the quick responses guys!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Really: Thats really short! :D However, since 5.3 it gets even shorter

```
$bar = $foo ?: 'bar';
```

Comment: It's still `?:` in 5.3 (not `:?`), but you can leave out the middle part now.

Answer (score 7):

Try to think not only of quicker *writing* but also of quicker reading.
Eventually you will learn that comfortable reading is way more important than these silly tricks in writing.

Comment: Agreed. If you want quicker coding, use your IDE's macro function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$foo = false;
$bar = $foo ?: 'bar';
```

should return 'bar

```
$foo = true;
$bar = $foo ?: 'bar';
```

should return true;

AS of 5.3

Answer (score 1):

"Quicker" by what metric?

In terms of runtime, this will *never* be your bottleneck, so don't worry about it.

In terms of legibility, the following is clearly easier to read:

```
$foo = false; // done elsewhere

$bar = $foo;
if (!$bar) {  // I've assumed from your examples that
              // you meant more than just "not false"
   $bar = 'bar';
}
```

Comment: Go on... put some braces in there.

Comment: Not really... he assigns `$foo` to `$bar` only if `$foo` evaluates to `TRUE`, otherwise `'bar'`. However, your example will modify `$foo` as well.

Comment: @Archimedix, @Martinho: Read it again.

Comment: I disagree: If you are familiar with the ternary-operator its more readable, than that.

Comment: @KingCrunch: You certainly have the right to disagree. Still, I'm more than familiar with the ternary conditional operator and I still find the above far easier to follow at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

My concern is that you could have a value that casts to false

```
$age = 0;
$myAge = $age ? $age : 21; //If no age assume drinking age
```

You wont get that with a direct, type sensitive comparison

```
if ($age ==== false) { 
  //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that's always forgotten, but there is also a Perl-esque syntax:

```
$foo = $foo   or   $foo = "bar";
```

Or in your case just:

```
$foo   or   $foo = "bar";
```

I'm often using excessive spaces to keep it readable. Most importantly it really does no assignment unless $foo is false.

Comment: It is indeed better than the full ternary operator, and it's not just quicker, but shorter too: `$x = expensive_function() ? expensive_function() : 1;` ==> `$x = expensive_function() or $x = 1;`

Comment: @biziclop Maybe you meant `$x = expensive_function() ?: 1`? Because your solution always returns a boolean, which may be not wanted.