# C#'s null coalescing operator (??) in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator, php-7

Is there a ternary operator or the like in PHP that acts like `??` of C#?

`??` in C# is clean and shorter, but in PHP you have to do something like:

```
// This is absolutely okay except that $_REQUEST['test'] is kind of redundant.
echo isset($_REQUEST['test'])? $_REQUEST['test'] : 'hi';

// This is perfect! Shorter and cleaner, but only in this situation.
echo null? : 'replacement if empty';

// This line gives error when $_REQUEST['test'] is NOT set.
echo $_REQUEST['test']?: 'hi';
```

Comment: `?:` is very close to `??`.  In fact, `?:` actually catches more null-like cases than `??`; `??` is specifically for `null` and `!Nullabe<T>.HasValue`.  You sound like you're looking for something more like JavaScript's `||` operator.  It's like `?:`, but JavaScript doesn't complain about referencing undefined keys/members--though it does throw an error if you try to reference a key/member of undefined/null, so you can only go one level.

Comment: @dpp, Why did you say `someres` then changed it to `test`?

Comment: Check out version 7. We finally have that.

Comment: Php 7 has this feature. Please check https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary

Comment: As noted, this will be in PHP 7.  In earlier versions, I think this is one of the few valid use cases for the error suppression operator, e.g. `echo @$_REQUEST['someres'] ?: 'hi';` which suppresses the error.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

PHP 7 adds the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';
```

You could also look at short way of writing PHP's ternary operator [?:](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (PHP >=5.3 only)

```
// Example usage for: Short Ternary Operator
$action = $_POST['action'] ?: 'default';

// The above is identical to
$action = $_POST['action'] ? $_POST['action'] : 'default';
```

And your comparison to C# is not fair. "in PHP you have to do something like" - In C# you will also have a runtime error if you try to access a non-existent array/dictionary item.

Comment: Really? So if I'm accessing a non-existent array element? I will get error too, yes, that makes sense.

Comment: @NullUserException: thanks, I always get in stuck with such sort of phrases :-(

Comment: It's a perfectly fair statement.  The `System.Linq` namespace provides extension method `TSource Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index)` for arrays and such.  `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` itself provides [a method for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639.aspx): `bool IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)`.  This method returns two values, as C# differentiates more explicitly between `null` and unset.  If you'd rather treat `null` and unset equally, you could easily write an extension method.

Comment: @Zenexer: the question was not about methods, but about operators. Thanks for downvoting without any reason.

Comment: @zerkms Look at it from the point of view of the person asking the question.  They want a solution, not strictly an operator.  An answer is not the place for you to get defensive.

Comment: @Zenexer: please read the question once again - OP asked about how operator specifically works. The question is about the general operator behaviour, not about a particular programming issue.

Comment: @zerkms You are retaliating inappropriately.  If you must retaliate at all, go downvote my post instead of insisting that I interpret the question literally.

Comment: @Zenexer: well, you think my answer is incorrect. I think that yours is wrong. Questions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33427/discussion-between-zenexer-and-zerkms)

Comment: @zerkms, Wow you have run-time errors and you are complaining? Here I've got to spend hours finding out where the silent errors are hiding. Give me all your errors.

Comment: @Pacerier "Wow you have run-time errors and you are complaining?" --- not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @zerkms, Ah the luxury of strongly-typed languages, as opposed to [loosely typed](https://www.google.com/search?q=fails+silently) ones.

Comment: @Pacerier okay. Still not sure where I was complaining about anything here.

Comment: What in the world does "PHP you have to do something like ---" mean?  Very unclear.

Comment: @Kzqai check the history of edits: someone else removed quotes and something else, so it's lost the original meaning. I'm going to fix it now.

Comment: While `??` certainly makes some cases easier to write and read, I would prefer it to emulate `empty($var) ? 'default' : $var`. Empty would not raise error if there is no `$var` set (just like `isset`), but it would also check for emptyness (like `(bool)$var === false`, I think), which is likely to be more useful in web development, full of user inputs ;-)

Comment: @pilat "Empty would not raise error if there is no $var set" --- that's actually a not valid justification: you should **NEVER** address variables that might be not declared. It simply is already a mistake itself, so it should be fixed, not mitigated.

Comment: @zerkms in web development, we deal with user input a lot. Even APIs may produce structures with "variable number of fields" and we still need to integrate with them. There is a reason behind `isset` function, after all. My example: `empty($var)` was not very good, however. I should have written something like `empty($var['key'])` (assuming that $var is indeed defined, but I have doubts about the 'key' existence), but it was omitted for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @pilat indeed, `empty($var['key'])` makes much more sense (and it should have been used as an example instead) :-)

Answer (score 53):

The [Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary), (`??`) has been accepted and implemented in [PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php6). It differs from the [short ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (`?:`) in that `??` will suppress the `E_NOTICE` that would otherwise occur when attempting to access an array where it doesn't have a key. The first example in the RFC gives:

```
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// equivalent to: $username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';
```

Notice that the `??` operator does not require the manual application of `isset` to prevent the `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: It works anywhere `isset()` does, actually, so it works for variables and properties, too.

Comment: Also, a nice feature is that you can chain it, thus: `$_GET['user'] ?? $_SESSION['user'] ?? 'bob';` - and as it short-circuits, you can even do function calls. Plus, unlike `isset($foo) ? $foo : $bar`, if it's a function call (e.g. `foo()[0]`), it won't evaluate it twice. :)

Comment: @AndreaFaulds You should say that unlike the plain ternary you can chain it without [traumatic brain injury](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142538/strange-behaviour-ternary-operator).

Comment: Well, you can do that with the short ternary operator `?:` too, it's a different use case.

Answer (score 10):

I use function. Obviously it is not operator, but seems cleaner than your approach:

```
function isset_or(&$check, $alternate = NULL)
{
    return (isset($check)) ? $check : $alternate;
}
```

Usage:

```
isset_or($_REQUEST['test'],'hi');
```

Comment: Why pass the `$check` var as reference?

Comment: @AxelA.Grazx: I am passing as reference, because if it is not sent as reference, `$_REQUEST['test']` value will be calculated before function call and then passed to function. It will throw `Undefined index: test` error if `$REQUEST` array doesn't have this element. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Ohhh... Now I see... Nice approach.

Comment: This answer should be higher - I've been using the same approach and it's very neat.

Comment: This has the negative side effect of setting the checked key to null: http://3v4l.org/9vmFR  Here's a case where that can be particularly problematic: http://3v4l.org/sMsKD

Answer (score 6):

Prior to PHP 7, there isn't. If you need to involve `isset`, the pattern to use is `isset($var) ? $var : null`. There's no `?:` operator that includes the characteristics of `isset`.

Comment: And this basically makes it useless for most cases. :/

Comment: I still find a lot of use cases for it; it's basically PHP's equivalent to Javascript's `||` operator, which is very handy. :)

Answer (score 4):

`??` is binary in C#, not ternary. And it has no equivalence in PHP prior to PHP 7.

Comment: The equivalent is `?:` in PHP 5.3. E.g. `test ?: ifNull` === `test ? test : ifNull`. In other words, `?:` can be either binary or ternary in PHP as the middle operand is optional.

Comment: Actually, `??` in C# is ternary.  It's syntactic sugar for a ternary operation.  It's just written in binary form.

Comment: @Zenexer: It's a binary operator, and it's not just syntactic sugar - `func() ?? otherfunc()` only calls `func` once, whereas `func()!=null ? func() : otherfunc()` calls it twice, so if `func` has side effects the results are completely different.

Comment: @aboveyou00 Interesting; I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

An identical operator doesn't exist as of PHP 5.6, but you can make a function that behaves similarly.

```
/**
 * Returns the first entry that passes an isset() test.
 *
 * Each entry can either be a single value: $value, or an array-key pair:
 * $array, $key.  If all entries fail isset(), or no entries are passed,
 * then first() will return null.
 *
 * $array must be an array that passes isset() on its own, or it will be
 * treated as a standalone $value.  $key must be a valid array key, or
 * both $array and $key will be treated as standalone $value entries. To
 * be considered a valid key, $key must pass:
 *
 *     is_null($key) || is_string($key) || is_int($key) || is_float($key)
 *         || is_bool($key)
 *
 * If $value is an array, it must be the last entry, the following entry
 * must be a valid array-key pair, or the following entry's $value must
 * not be a valid $key.  Otherwise, $value and the immediately following
 * $value will be treated as an array-key pair's $array and $key,
 * respectfully.  See above for $key validity tests.
 */
function first(/* [(array $array, $key) | $value]... */)
{
    $count = func_num_args();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++)
    {
        $arg = func_get_arg($i);

        if (!isset($arg))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (is_array($arg))
        {
            $key = func_get_arg($i + 1);

            if (is_null($key) || is_string($key) || is_int($key) || is_float($key) || is_bool($key))
            {
                if (isset($arg[$key]))
                {
                    return $arg[$key];
                }

                $i++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        return $arg;
    }

    if ($i < $count)
    {
        return func_get_arg($i);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
$option = first($option_override, $_REQUEST, 'option', $_SESSION, 'option', false);
```

This would try each variable until it finds one that satisfies `isset()`:

1. `$option_override`
2. `$_REQUEST['option']`
3. `$_SESSION['option']`
4. `false`

If 4 weren't there, it would default to `null`.

Note: There's a simpler implementation that uses references, but it has the side effect of [setting the tested item to null if it doesn't already exist](http://3v4l.org/9vmFR).  This [can be problematic](http://3v4l.org/csruJ) when the size or truthiness of an array matters.

Comment: doesn't answer the OPs question which was "does such an operator exist". Also, @LukLed's answer (posted months after this) demonstrates something similar without the need to deconstruct associative array indexing.

Comment: @benrifkah LukLed's answer has the negative side effect of setting the specified key to null: http://3v4l.org/9vmFR  If you take the reference of a key that doesn't exist, it will be created.  It's particularly problematic if you're working with arrays that don't exist: http://3v4l.org/sMsKD

Comment: I'm seeing strange results from this "first" function. Care to chat about it? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79985/chat-about-php-null-coalesce-function

Comment: @benrifkah Sorry for the late reply; heading there now.