# game.HUD = game.HUD || {} meaning

Tags: syntax, namespaces, melonjs

I'm following [melon js tutorial](http://melonjs.github.io/tutorial/). This is at the top of my HUD.js file.

```
game.HUD = game.HUD || {}
```

I've seen this before in other examples. What does the `namespace.something = namespace.something || {}` syntax mean and why is it needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is a null coalesce operator so you are saying in that line return my object if it already exists or a new object if it does not (is null)

Comment: Ah, is this sort of the same thing as PHP's `$input = (isset($_GET['_input']) ? ($_GET['_input']) : 0);` ?

Comment: Sort of.  I'm not amazing at PHP so you might want to check with an expert but afaik PHP doesn't have a null coalescing operator.  The `?:` operator you listed there is a ternary operator.  How you used it performs a very similar function to the null coalesce.

This link might help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278835/cs-null-coalescing-operator-in-php