# Only output on one side of ternary in PHP, is there a cleaner way to write this?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have the following line of code:

```
<input id="b_first_name" type="text" name="b_first_name" class="required"
    value="<?= $this->settings['fill_form'] ? "Bob" : "" ?>">
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this?  I don't like writing a ternary where one side doesn't need output, it feels dirty. I am looking to output "Bob" ONLY if the setting "fill_form" is set to true. I wish I could something like this, but neither work:

```
<input id="b_first_name" type="text" name="b_first_name" class="required"
    value="<?= $this->settings['fill_form'] ? "Bob" ?>">
```

or

```
<input id="b_first_name" type="text" name="b_first_name" class="required"
    value="<?= if ($this->settings['fill_form']) "Bob" ?>">
```

Comment: There's no cleaner way. Another option is  `<? if ($this->settings['fill_form']) echo "Bob" ?>`

Comment: `<?php  if ($this->settings['fill_form']) echo "Bob";?>` would work if you prefer it to the first option. Or: `<?=!$this->settings['fill_form'] ?:'Bob';?>`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278835/cs-null-coalescing-operator-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing the echo.

```
<input id="b_first_name" type="text" name="b_first_name" class="required"
value="<?php if ($this->settings['fill_form']) echo "Bob";  ?>">
```

But I would put the brackets as well

```
<input id="b_first_name" type="text" name="b_first_name" class="required"
value="<?php if ($this->settings['fill_form']) { echo "Bob"; } ?>">
```