# error_reporting(0) function, error with empty variable in my form

Tags: php

**More clarification:**
*I have a checkbox with name="agree" in my register form, and the user must mark this value="agree" to complete the process of registration, if this checkbox not marked an error message will appear to the user. As a test I tried to submit the form without mark this checkbox but I found this INDEX error appeared saying: [ Notice: Undefined index: agree in ] even the error message for the user has appeared too.*

I have a checkbox and radio fields in my form, these fields are optional. So when I submit my form and these values are empty I get an INDEX error. Is there any way to avoid that error without using error_reporting(0) fuction:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>

<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $agree = $_POST['agree'];
   }
?>
```

Comment: is there some php hiding somewhere?

Comment: Where's the submit button or AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

You only checked the `submit` button request field. But the `agree` checkbox needs a separate [`isset`](http://php.net/isset)/[`empty`](http://php.net/empty) if you want to suppress notices.

An alternative, which also shouldn't be used thoughtlessly, is the [`@()`](http://php.net/) error *display* omitter. It's universally despised, but more concise:

```
$agree = @($_POST["agree"]);
```

Take in mind that unlike `isset`/`empty` it doesn't completely obliterate notices. It merely prevents the default notice display. **They still show up in logs…**

Which is rarely what you want. But if it's an actual (TOS?) "agree" checkbox, it might well be a practical use case. (- Otherwise you had to implement a custom log scheme/table for monitoring user preferences and terms of service haters. You know, if that's what it's about.)

There's also the upcoming [PHP7 null coalesce operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278835/cs-null-coalescing-operator-in-php), `$agree = $_POST["agree"] ?? false;` btw. It's likewise readable but fully suppresses notices like the `isset`/`empty` combo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a conditional with the `isset` or `empty` function. Assuming you use `agree` in as a bit value you could use the ternary operator to set the value like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>

<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $agree = !empty($_POST['agree']) ? 1: 0;
   }
?>
```

Per the [empty manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php),

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

Comment: What happens, what do you get for a message? What is the usage of `$agree` later?

Comment: I have a checkbox with name="agree" in my register form, and the user must mark this value="agree" to complete the process of registration, if this checkbox not marked an error message will appear to the user. As a test I tried to submit the form without mark this checkbox but I found this INDEX error appeared saying: [ Notice: Undefined index: agree in ] even the error message for the user has appeared too.