# "or" assignments in php 5

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

In javascript, you can do...

```
var this_is_null = null;
var this_is_real = 'Hello';

var result = this_is_null || this_is_real;

alert(result);
```

Resulting popup:

```
Hello
```

Now, I'm trying to do similar in PHP, with something like

```
$this_is_null = null;
$this_is_real = "Hello";

$result = $this_is_null or $this_is_real;
$result2 = $this_is_null || $this_is_real;

PRINT($result2);
PRINT($result);
```

However, this results in

```
1
```

So, is there an equivalent in PHP to or-based variable assignment?

http://viper-7.com/57VRKQ

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278835/cs-null-coalescing-operator-in-php

Comment: Ahh, ?? operator... looks good if environment I was working in wasn't PHP5.

Comment: There are write ups on that question for earlier versions.

Answer (score 3):

Even shorter:

```
$result = $this_is_null ?: $this_is_real;
```

For reference, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary.

Comment: Has the same issues as lanis's answer... very good answer, works for the example case in the question, but doesn't quite hit feature parity with the || variable assignment because it doesn't work if the variable hasn't been declared (one common use for the || in variable declaration in javascript).
For example:
`$thing = array(); $thing[0] = "real";
$result2 = $thing[1] ? $thing[1]: $thing[0] ;` would give an error.
I'm thinking of using isset in there, but then it wouldn't check if it's not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead :

```
$result2 = $this_is_null ? $this_is_null : $this_is_real ;
```

Comment: Very similar to the || in variable declaration, although I'm trying to few test cases and noticing it's different in the case if you're assigning from an index. 
For example:
`$thing = array(); $thing[0] = "real";
$result2 = $thing[1] ? $thing[1]: $thing[0] ;`