# Fallthrough variable assignment in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coalesce function for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013493/coalesce-function-for-php)

I'm not sure what this is normally called, but I hope the title communicates well enough. What I have is a handful of variables some of which might be null.

I want to do:

```
$a = $b || $c || $d;
```

Where $a ends up being = to the first non-null variable.

Comment: Are you trying to assign the contents of b OR c OR d to a :\?

Comment: Wrong language for this. It would work in Ruby or JavaScript. In PHP, AFAIK, you need to go with the trinary operator and write `$b !== null ? $b : ($c !== null ? $c : $d)`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013493/coalesce-function-for-php

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, PHP doesn't support this in the same way JavaScript does.

You can, however do something like this:

```
$a = $b ? $b : ($c ? $c : $d);
```

---

A more general solution:

```
function fallthrough($arr) {
    //$arr should be an array of possible values. The first non-null value is returned
    do $a = array_shift($arr);
    while($a === null && $arr);
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: So, what would be the best way to do this in PHP? Clearly I can't just nest ternary operators as that will get insane with more variables. Do I just have a big if elseif block?

Comment: Careful - if `$b` is `"0"`, it will fall through. To be more precise, it will fall through on any falsy value. If you really need only `null` to fall through, you need to explicitly test.

Comment: What you could do is define a function. I'll edit my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$a = 0;
$b = false;
$c = true; //should become this
$d = '1';
$e =  $a ?: $b ?: $c ?: $d;
var_dump($e);
//bool(true)

//should be '1' if order is different
$e =  $a ?: $b ?: $d ?: $c;
var_dump($e);
//string(1) "1"
```

... however `?:` is kinda new, you will confuse your colleagues / fellow coders.

Comment: Oh, and as stated: fails on all falsy values, not just NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. I think you'd have to use some other, more laborious, way. I.e. make an array of the variables, iterate through it until you find a non-null value and break the loop, like so:

```
$vars = array("b" => $b, "c" => $c, "d" => $d);

foreach($vars as $var) {
   if($var != null) {
      $a = $var;
      break;
   }
}
```

Well, like some other answers here say, you can use the shorthand way of writing this, but writing readable code is important too. The above code is pretty readable.