# Strange ternary operator

Tags: php

```
<?php echo (isset($var)) ?: $var; ?>
```

Is this syntax correct? What will this display if $var won't be set, empty string or null? Is it ok to use this?

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. It would echo `true` when `$var` is set but `$var` when `$var` is not set.

Comment: Is there any shortcut to display what I want - null when $var is not set?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013493/coalesce-function-for-php for more info.

Comment: Yes there is a shortcut, see my answer.

Comment: echo (isset($var)?'YES':'NO');

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<?php echo (isset($var)) ?: $var; ?>
```

do the same as this:

```
<?php
 if (isset($var)) {
  // do nothing
 } else {
  echo $var;
 }
?>
```

So you are trying to display variable if its empty/null/etc...

If function:

```
<?php $k= (cond ? do_if_true : do_if_false); ?>
```

`$k` could be new variable, `echo`, etc.
`cond` - `isset`, `$z==$y`, etc.

Comment: That's actually not true. It's functionally equivalent to: `echo isset($var) ? isset($var) : $var` which is technically not the same as your example.

Comment: ($var) ?: '' would solve all of my problems, though as far as I know this isn't equivalent to isset($var) ? $var : '', am I right about this one?

Comment: I just tried to run your example and server didn't display any results without `''`, i get error `syntax error, unexpected ':'`, so it might be necessary

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct, the usage is not. Say here:

```
$var = something();
echo $var ?: 'false';
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$var = something();
if ($var) {
    echo $var;
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

or shorthand for `$var ? $var : 'false'`.

Your example is pointless since it outputs the result of `isset($var)` (`true`) if `$var` *is set* and `$var` otherwise.

You need `echo isset($var) ? $var : null` or `if (isset($var)) echo $var`, and there's no shortcut for it.

Answer (score 0):

The code no have sense, generates a notice or echo 1, you can't print a $var which isn't set

Comment: "isn't isset" Really? Really?! ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Corrected :P, i'm not english, and you can also not put -1 at random

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is fine.

If $var is set then it will output, if it is not, it will throw an Notice about the echo of $var which is unset.

if your error_reporting is set to E_NONE then you will just see a white screen, if the $var is set then you will see the value of $var

Answer (score 0):

This will echo $var either way.

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

So if $var is set, it echos $var (since that evaluates to TRUE), if its not set to anything or evaluates to false, your manually asking it to echo $var anyway.

ideally you want:

```
(condition  ?  if_true_then_do_this : if_false_then_do_this)
```

in shorthand this becomes

```
   (condition ? ? false)
```

and since you have specified $var in both places, you will get $var, either way. You want this:

```
echo ($var?:"null");
```

Comment: Won't this generate a notice if $var won't be set?

Comment: no, it will echo null. I just created a test script with that one line in it and it printed null to the screen.

Comment: If I set $var = 5; or someting like that, it prints out the value of $var.

Comment: Then it means that if(isset($var)) is exactly the same as if($var) ? I've always wondered if it's ok to do that :D

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this syntax is incorrect.
By the time of echoing, **all** variables have to be set **and properly formatted**.
Otherwise means a developer have no idea where their variables come from and what do they contain - a straight road to injection.

So, the proper syntax would be

```
<?=$var?>
```

As for the ternaries - I don't like them.

Comment: To get technical - the _syntax_ is correct. The logic is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php (isset($var)) ? echo "" : echo $var; ?>
```

you can use this one.

Comment: If $var is set you echo empty string and if isn't set you echo $var?? Wtf?

Comment: @Sam that's OP's broken logic. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯