# Is there a php operator similar to javascript's "||"?

Tags: javascript, php, operators

In javascript the logical or-operator returns the first *truthy* operand, e.g.

```
var x = null || 5 || 1;
```

assigns 5 to x.
Is there somthing similar for php?

Comment: Yes, its called "OR" used in `if-else` statements.

Comment: does it work that way `||` did it in my example

Comment: Read about [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) in PHP.net after understanting how php language works.

Comment: `||` will cast any operands into boolean values.

Comment: This is called a "null coalescing" or in PHP/JavaScript it's really an "empty coalescing" I guess. There are actually lots of duplicates of this worded in various ways on SO...here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013493/coalesce-function-for-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case you describe is: *if the value exists use it, otherwise use a default value*. This is a pretty common pattern.

As of PHP 5.3 you can do:

```
$var = $foo ?: 5;
```

In older versions you can do:

```
$var = $foo ? $foo : 5;
```

---

Note that in:

```
var x = null || 5 || 1;
```

the final path `|| 1` will never get chosen because `5` is never [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: it was just an example

Comment: Just so you stay updated for the future, I'd suggest that you add in PHP 7's `??` to your answer.  PHP is finally getting a true null coalescing operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

`||` is a logical operator in PHP and many other programming languages. Learn more about logical operators in the official [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

What you are searching for is a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), which is the following in PHP:

```
$valueOne = $null ? $null : $five;
```

Since PHP 5.3 you may use the short form:

```
$valueOne = $null ?: $five;
```

And since its associativity is `left` you may use it multiple times successively:

```
$valueOne = $null ?: $five ?: $one;
```